# Parsing unstructured data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a unstructured Data frame in python  which has two variables X and Y.  Every observation in X is array and Y is class variable which looks like

```
             X           Y
      1. [ [ 1,2] ]      a
      2. [ [ 2,3] ]      b
```

I want to Have it like

```
 1.   1    2     a
 2.   2    3     b 

I have tried option from numpy to data frame but not working
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':[[[1,2]],[[3,4]]],'Y':['a','b']})

def expand(x):
     x=x['X'][0]
     return x
df['X1'],df['X2']=zip(*df.apply(expand,axis=1))
df=df.drop(['X'],axis=1)
```

Explanation: using zip() with apply(axis=1), we can generate 2 new columns using 'X'.

For many elements in 'X':

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'X':[[[1,2,3,4]],[[3,4,5,6]]],'Y':['a','b']})

def expand(x):
    new_columns=x['X'][0]
    return new_columns+[x['Y']]
df=pd.DataFrame(zip(*df.apply(expand,axis=1))).T
```

[image]

Now, 'X' can have any number of elements. I used 'X' with 4 elements for example.

Comment: Thank u mehul ..I have one more question what if instade of just two elements in array if we have 100 elements in each observation array of X

Comment: so like you wish to make 100 new columns?

Comment: I want to make new 100 columns

Comment: Thank u so much ...Mehul